# apache2 Ubuntu django : can't upload my django app

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql, django

I tried to upload my Django 2.2 project, but I get this error in Ubuntu 18.04 when I type `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` :

```
(13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=7692): 
Unable to stat Python home /root/project_name/venv/. 
Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. 
Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/django_proj.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /root/project_name/static
    <Directory /root/project_name/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /meida /root/project_name/meida
    <Directory /root/project_name/meida>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /root/project_name/zettapc>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /root/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/root/project_name python-home=/root/project_name/venv/
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app 

</VirtualHost>
```

and this is my wsgi configuration

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Is there something I've missed, or something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @karel , please do you have any idea?

Comment: Your error message is the same error message that a user would get if he is running a Django project in PyCharm IDE and he initialized the project incorrectly. If it's true that you are using PyCharm, I have already answered a question like this at Stack Overflow and I can provide a link.

Comment: Maybe relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings How is your WSGI configured?

Comment: @karel no , its not , i used vs code to build and apache2 ubuntu to deploy

Comment: @BrianZ i update my question with wsgi code , the link doesnt work in my case , i much appreciate your helps

Comment: @BrianZ is there something i have to change please ?

Comment: I would check if WSGI is set to use the right Python version: https://serverfault.com/questions/157854/python-version-for-mod-wsgi

Comment: i solved the encoding issues by chmod +x /path , but now i get this error (permission denied: mod_wsgi Call to fopen() failed for 'path/wsgi.py)